# Rails.root with Dir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, directory

I seem to see a lot of people using `Rails.root` with `Dir[]`

Example: `Dir[Rails.root.join('app', '*')`

However, this seems unnecessary because functionally, it looks like `Dir['app/*]` does the exact same thing (and I personally prefer `Dir['app/*']`  over `Dir[Rails.root.join('app', '*']`).

I’m wondering is there any reason to use `Rails.root` with `Dir` or is it ok to not use `Rails.root`?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Anytime `Dir.chdir` is called (which could happen without you realizing it), it changes the assumed root. When `Rails.root` is used with `Dir`, the response stays consistent (which is what you want). However, when `'app'` is used, the response is inconsistent, which will cause issues in your code.

You can play around with by copy / pasting the below text:

```
# copy / paste this into your rails console and view the results
def test
  puts 'start:'
  puts Dir[Rails.root.join('app')]
  puts Dir['app']
  Dir.chdir('app') do 
    puts nil
    puts 'note that Rails.root does not change but app does:'
    puts Dir[Rails.root.join('app')]
    puts Dir['app']
  end
  puts nil
  puts 'back:'
  puts Dir[Rails.root.join('app')]
  puts Dir['app']
end
test
```

More info can be found [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Dir.html#method-c-chdir)